# GWT: Converting a date to GMT TimeZone

Tags: javascript, gwt, vaadin7

I'm trying to convert the selected date value by the user to GMT Timezone but i did'nt find a solution.

I'm using Vaadin so i'm writing GWT code which will be converted to JavaScript. The problem is that not all classes can be used because they could not be converted to JavaScript.

I tried this :

```
DateTimeFormat dft = DateTimeFormat.getFullDateFormat();
String formattedDate = dft.format(selected, (com.google.gwt.i18n.shared.TimeZone) TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
Date dateRes = new Date(formattedDate);
```

I tried this also:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX");
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
System.out.println("Current date and time in GMT: " + df.format(selected));
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(selected);
df.setCalendar(c);
```

In the 2 above solutions the code could not be compiled.

I wrote this :

```
if (selected.getTimezoneOffset() != 0) {
  selected.setMinutes(selected.getMinutes() + selected.getTimezoneOffset());
}
```

The code was compiled but the problem was the following for example :
When the use choose the 15/04/2015 the 
selected date will have this value: date :

```
Wed Apr 15 00:00:00 GMT+100 2015
```

The converted date will be :

```
Tue Apr 14 23:00:00 GMT+100 2015
```

Is there another way to do it?

Comment: I use http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/DateTimeFormat.html with no problems, but I am not using Vaadin.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `java.util.TimeZone`, then try using `com.google.gwt.i18n.client.TimeZone` instead.